# Failed to run docker with exported model in GoogleCP Vision AutoML Model

Tags: docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-automl, automl

I trained an image classifying model using GCP AutoML Vision and I would like to deploy it in my own web app using Docker. Following the [tutorial from GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial), I exported my Vision autoML model to a **saved_model.pb** and managed to copy it to my local drive.

```html
sudo docker run --rm --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} -p ${PORT}:8501 -v ${YOUR_MODEL_PATH}:/tmp/mounted_model/0001 -t ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}
```

When I tried to run the docker image, there's an error. Error message below:

```html
2020-03-18 06:52:52.851811: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:462] Adding/updating models.
2020-03-18 06:52:52.851825: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:559]  (Re-)adding model: default
2020-03-18 06:52:52.859873: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: default version: 1}
2020-03-18 06:52:52.859923: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: default version: 1}
2020-03-18 06:52:52.859938: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: default version: 1}
2020-03-18 06:52:52.860387: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:363] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /tmp/mounted_model/0001
2020-03-18 06:52:52.860426: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /tmp/mounted_model/0001
2020-03-18 06:52:52.861256: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2020-03-18 06:52:52.861345: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:310] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 916 microseconds.
2020-03-18 06:52:52.861357: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
```

I did some researches online, it seems the problem lies on the exporting part of the model, which GCP does not offer any options when I'm exporting the model. I could really use the help, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the model doesn't have a graph corresponding to the [serving tag](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/tag_constants.py#L26).

I found a similar issue reported in the [Tensorflow github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/491). To inspect the available tag-sets in a saved model you can use the [SavedModel CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model), you can use the saved_model_cli to inspect the tags:

$ saved_model_cli show --dir ./modelDir

I found how  add the serving tag to the model from Tensorflow Hub and it seems that using Transfer Learning could help you to export or save the model with the [serving tag](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub).